I'm having difficulties trying to install tailwindcss on my project
The terminal throws an error of existing file, but when trying to initialise tailwindcss throws the same error.
nicolocartesan@Air-di-Nicolo Tailwind starter % npm install -D tailwindcss
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/nicolocartesan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/c6/0b
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/tailwindcss: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/nicolocartesan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/c6/0b'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/nicolocartesan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/c6/0b
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/nicolocartesan/.npm/_logs/2024-06-05T11_26_34_328Z-debug-0.log

And when trying to run tailwindcss it throws the same error
Can anyone help me please, thank you so much!
I tried to look online and I tried to use --force but it throws the same error, I don't know if I should delete the existing package or try something else.
